# Getting error while trying to run android app by flutter run

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

Suddenly I started getting this error while trying to run my app created using flutter and dart. I am new to android development. Any help is appreciated.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\DEVELOPEMENT\Android\flutter_projects\nav_app\build\app\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\signing-config.json (Access is denied)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the file at this location
`D:\DEVELOPEMENT\Android\flutter_projects\nav_app\build\app\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\signing-config.json`

and do a `flutter clean`.

Answer (score 1):

This is causing your error `signing-config.json (Access is denied)`

Delete this file and it should work, located at
`D:\DEVELOPEMENT\Android\flutter_projects\nav_app\build\app\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\signing-config.json`.